# What approach to use for detecting the release of the basketball?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm on a project where I analyze free throw shots. For now, I am able to detect and track the ball. To move on, I need to detect the frame number where the shooter releases the basketball, meaning there should be a separation between shooter's hand and the ball. I don't want to dive into hand tracking and I am searching for a quick way to detect the frame where the shooter releases the ball. I thought about checking the sudden changes in ball speed but in that case if the shooter dribbles the ball before shooting it, I might get an unexpected result. What would be the best approach for the purpose?

[An example footage that I am using ( like the first 10 seconds or so )](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNExV32NnBg)

Comment: The path of the shot should be a parabola should it not?  The shot starts where (working backward) it deviates from the parabola?

Comment: ^ also that link doesn't seem to be viewable

Comment: What do you mean by deviating from the parabola?  And yes, the ball will have a parabolic path.

Comment: The ball follows a parabolic path. Extend that path infinitely. The true path the the ball takes will match up (more or less) with the ideal parabola while in the air, but while in the hands of the player, it will not.

Comment: I got it now, thanks. The detection will work backwards and constantly checks if the ball is in a parabolic path or not. I am not sure if this will give the exact frame I need but we'll see.